# Xcode 11.2 - Unable to install App file to device?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently updated my OS to Catalina, and updated Xcode to 11.2. Since doing so, when I try to run a release version of my app on my device, I'm simply given the error:

> Unable to install the app.

When I tap 'details', it provides me with the following:

> App installation failed Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit Code: -402620395
>   Failure Reason: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was
>   not found.
>
> User Info: {
>       DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
>       "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011baff6e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109  1   DTDeviceKitBase
>   0x000000011baffde9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792   2   DTDeviceKitBase
>   0x000000011bb3f56a **90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken
>   installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke
>   + 164     3   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010356f156 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73    4   DTDeviceKitBase
>
>   0x000000011bb3f301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken
>   installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] +
>   1589  5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011b9c7a25
>   __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352
>   + 4523    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001036a03ba __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK** + 7     7   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001036a1a92 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809    8
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff68220583
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12     9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6822150e _dispatch_client_callout + 8     10  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00007fff68226ace _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597  11 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff68227452
>   _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363   12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff68230a9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598   13 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6847a71b
>   _pthread_wqthread + 290   14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6847a57b start_wqthread + 15 ); }

My provisioning profiles are 100% correct, as are my certificates. I have no idea why this is happening, and I've tried absolutely everything to get it to install/run. I've tried:

- Double checked that 'Scheme' has release checked under the 'Run' tab
- Confirmed that correct provisioning profile is selected
- Removing the app from my device
- Creating new provisioning profiles
- Changing my bundle ID
- Creating new certificates
- Cleaning the build folder, restarting Xcode
- Reinstalling Xcode
- Deleting the Derived Data folder

**NONE of the above has worked.** I've been at this for 2 days now - help is appreciated. The only way I'm able to install the app file successfully to my device is if I upload it to TestFlight first (which, I can't feasibly do every time I want to test a small change).

Comment: Have you been able to verify this with a second device?

Comment: Yes, I've tried installing the app to 2 different devices, same error each time. @CodeBender

Comment: You mentioned that you updated to 11.2 recently, is this the first time you have built with Xcode 11.x? For distribution profiles in Apple's developer site, there is a new option specific to Xcode 11 & are you using that?

Comment: I previously had XCode 11.1, so I updated the distribution profiles then to the newer versions (Apple Distribution & Apple Development). @CodeBender

Comment: FWIW, I'm running into the same exact issue with 11.2, while trying to deploy a "Profile" build to my device. Running 'Debug' builds works fine.  And I'm running Mojave, not Catalina.

Comment: I'm having the same issue lately when adding certain frameworks/libraries. I can't pinpoint it yet with which frameworks it's happening, but its clearly linked for me. Maybe its similar for you.

Comment: Are you using automatic signing or manual?

Comment: Manual - but I've tried switching to automatic to see if it solves the problem and it does not. @shim

Comment: Have you tried selecting Ad Hoc as the distribution option in Xcode instead of App Store (not as a solution, just curious if it also fails)? There is a difference between a release provisioning profile for the App Store (i.e. what is used with TestFlight) and one for Ad Hoc.

Comment: Also under File > Workspace Settings under "Build System" what do you have selected?

Comment: You can also check in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles and see what provisioning profiles are there. (Use spacebar preview to see summary of each profile's info.)

Comment: I know this isn't really what you want to do -- but have you tried re-downloaded Xcod 11.1 and using that in the meantime?  (I'm doing that now.)

Comment: Update: So when I switch to an Ad Hoc Distribution Profile, the app now installs to the device. That said, upon launch, it crashes without any explanation / console log. Before updating to XCode 11, this never happened. @shim

Comment: What version of iOS is your device running?

Comment: @shim Currently have 13.2 running.

Comment: And the app does not crash when running with Xcode attached? / did you check the crash logs on the device?

Comment: I can't believe it - hilariously I was never able to unpack 11.2.1 via the xip file, but they released it to the App Store and I was able to update. FINALLY solved the issue, in conjunction with using an Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile instead of just a regular Distribution Profile. Good work all. Thank you! @shim

Comment: It's driving me nuts!!! I still have this issue and none of the solutions here solved it. Are there any other ideas?

Comment: I face it 100 times per day, this is so crazy

Answer (score 35):

Go to File -> Workspace Settings, and make sure your build system is set to Legacy Build System.

I ran into the same issue on Catalina and Xcode 11.2 and this solved it for me.

As of Xcode 11 Apple is starting to enforce some of the build criteria that was previously only required for AppStore builds on .ipa extraction, and device builds.

So far I have encountered:

- Requiring the above legacy build system setting for device deployments for older projects or projects that use older frameworks
- Removing unused architectures to extract an ipa from an archive

Comment: Probably the same issue -- seeing a slightly different error, but no solutions here solved it.  The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620394
Failure Reason: The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

Comment: @drewster I had the same error as well, and it was related to unused architectures in the build.  Sometimes frameworks will specify x86 architectures over and above the arm architectures.  Running the [script specified in this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues-unsupported-architecture-x86/41416964#41416964) solved the issue for me.

Comment: Changing to Legacy Build System did not work for me unfortunately :/

Comment: Spent hours on this. I added a project in the workspace that generated a framework I created as a target. I then embedded/linked the main project in the workspace to that framework project. Using the new build system in 11.2.1 GM, exporting IN HOUSE would then show "Could not install..." on a supervised device. Reading this post, I then switched to Legacy Build System. What that did is show ERRORS!!! telling me lipo could not strip the wrong architecture when archiving. So that pointed in the right direction and I then fixed the framework that was not getting built properly. THANK YOU LEGACY!

Comment: In my case switch to legacy did not solved that. It was due to a change in the provisioning profile. I ended up delete the app from device and then the installation was successful.

Comment: Thank You!! In my case I needed to do what You and Vittal Pai told.

Comment: Legacy Build System is deprecated. This is what it tells in my Xcode editor.

Comment: @Markus yes it has been deprecated for a few years now, but still supported for now.  It does mean that XCode could stop support at any future date.  It is there to give developers an opportunity to update their projects before support for the legacy build system is dropped.

Answer (score 26):

For me, it's due to Dynamic Frameworks which I have added in the application. Initially, I have selected (Embed + Don't Sign) option for the dynamic frameworks.

Changing it to (Embed & Sign) for such frameworks resolved the issue for me.

[image]

Comment: Just added external framework with "Embed Without Sign", had the same issue.
Changed it to Embed & Sign - well done!

Comment: Thank You!! It was the "Pods_MyApp.framework" created by Cocoapods that needed "Embed & Sign". In my case I needed to do what You and Shim told.

Comment: In my case, it was actually opposite, by mistake I clicked on Embed & sign in for Google sign in and it was giving error. When I changed to Do not Embed, it worked.

Answer (score 22):

Here is what works for me:

1. Remove the app and profile from device
2. Reinstall them again.

Comment: Classical solution :)

Comment: Facing this issue multiple times with Xcode 11.3, this is the fastest and simplest solution.

Comment: Oh, God! Sometimes it's so irritating, I have updated pods tried many other things but this solved me... weird

Answer (score 13):

Use Automatically manage signing

Solve this issue.

[image: checked auto signing]

Answer (score 8):

I manage to fix this issue when first I clean:

```
cmd + k
shift + cmd + k
```

and then I delete all the content of Deriving Data
the path of the folder should be like this

```
/Users/youruser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Or you can check it in

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations
```

Comment: This worked for me! I just did the first two shortcuts (`cmd + k`
and `shift + cmd + k`, then installing my app went accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

"-402620395 Failure Reason: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

I had this issue as well and solved it:

This means that your provisioning profile is not set to development. You need to create a new provisioning profile for development, which is different than a profile set for distribution. Then, in signing and capabilities, in your app settings on xcode, choose your development profile if you want to install on your device. Don't worry about distributing with your dev profile, you must choose which profile you want to use when pushing to app store (its set to none and you need to switch it).

Another solution would be choosing automatically manage signing in settings, but that has defaults set when pushing to app store which you might not want.

Comment: That's the real solution. Thank you!

Comment: working for me....

Answer (score 7):

Xcode error

> Unable to install the app.

Try to clean `Provisioning Profiles`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59292735/4770877)

```
Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators 
-> Right click on your device -> Show Provisioning Profiles...
-> Select Provisioning Profile -> - Remove selected profiles
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Delete derivedData folder

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is only related to **CODE SIGNING**

But, the key point to note here is, if you are using XCode 11.x version.
Not only the code signing in your project, but we should check the code signing in Thirdparty SDKs or dependencies that we add to our project.

Steps to verify the Code Signing of 3rd party SDks:

1. Download the source code of framework you need
2. Open the .xcproj file from the source code using XCode 11.x
3. Go to Targets -> Signing & Capabilities -> Select all tab -> Bundle Identifier
   If you see any unevenness in the identifier like, identifier with 4 seperators (Eg: com.company.mac.app)

   Change it to **com.*** and enter.
4. Make sure your XCODE COMMAND LINE TOOLS is set with XCode 11.x
5. Now, use  below command to rebuild the SDK, with the changes done in above step-3

   ```
     carthage build --no-skip-current --cache-builds --platform iOS
   ```
6. Now copy the framework generated from, **carthage** folder of source code, and replace the existing SDK in your project.

Repeat the same for process for all the 3rd party SDKs, in your project.

**NOTE:** Make sure you marked all the 3rd party SDKs as **Embed & Sign** in

```
Targets => General => Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content
```

Comment: Voted up for the bundle identifier fix, exactly my case.

Comment: In my case I needed to set all of the frameworks to "Do not Embed"

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was that the watch i was trying to use didn't unlock so i had to lock and unlock my watch again and then it was working fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is very strange but for me
`pod deintegrate`
and then `pod install` works.

Try out this solution if none of the above works for you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58145207/1791914). I had to clear out all of my old certificates and provisioning profiles and then create new certificates with "Apple Development" and "Apple Distribution," instead of the "iOS..." option.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to running distribution/release scheme. Changing the scheme to debug works for me. Hope this helps someone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue, it will cause the bundle to get the development provisioning profile instead of the distribution one which is what you might want.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was occurred by empty framework references in pbxproj. After removing them the problem was fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a codesign problem.

You can check iOS device logs to see which framework go wrong. filter 'installd' process. you can clearly say which framework codesign is wrong. so just find it out and fix it!

```
0x16fa53000 +[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:]: 77: Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.dABVKh/extracted/Your.app/Frameworks/xxx.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)
0x16fa53000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed
```

Comment: This makes the most sense as it describes exactly what the issue is

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are manually code signing your app and use a manual provisioning profile.

The problem occurs when you try to deploy your app to your physical device with **distribution provisioning profile**.

The solution is to create 2 different provisioning profiles; one for the development and the other is for distribution.

You can manage your provisioning profiles at https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list

After that, set your provisioning profiles as the image below:

[image]

---

### Note:

if you don't see your settings separated into two, you can use the tab above and set your profiles for each type of provisioning profiles (Debug and Release)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me:

1. Remove the app and profile from device
2. Reinstall app again.

In Some cases:

1. restart xcode
2. clean build
3. Reinstall the app again

Comment: clean build works for me , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and the problem was that I were using unpaid account and the total number of free development profiles was reached ,so you have to use paid account

detailes :

Failure Reason: The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached

Comment: I had the same problem. I read the Details and realized afterward

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running a project that had a library under `Embed Frameworks` which had `Code Sign on Copy` unchecked. Check-marking this resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this for a long time. What fixed it for me was deleting all the cache data generated by Xcode like Device Support, Archives, Derived data, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved after a whole day of mental agony.

For WebDriverAgentRunner package,  WebDriverAgentRunner --> Build Settings --> Product Bundle Identifier --> Provide a custom bundle identifier name

N.B: Copy the bundle identifier name you just provided.

Move to WebDriverAgentRunner --> Info --> Bundle Identifier --> Provide here the bundle identifier name you just copied

Follow the same step for the APP package you are trying to push.

Clean build folder and start building and APP should get pushed without an issue. Tested on Xcode 11.7

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 12, I got an error window saying: `Unable to install "AppName"`.
I clicked `Details` and found that **There was no space on my iPhone.**

Answer (score 0):

In My case just remove the existing build in my phone then run again its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have received this error message after I updated my MacOS (specific to Big Sur) and Xcode (to version 12.5).
For me what have solved the problem is just deleting the app from the device and re-install

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Faced this issue several times for several `xcode` and `cocoapods` versions.
This issues happen when each pod frameworks can't find specific `info.plist` file in project.
Of course I don't know why after `pod install`, each pod frameworks can't find `info.plist`.
In my case I've linked manually to the `project main` info.plist for each pod frameworks. :) Such as below.
[image]

After this, I could successfully install app to `device` or `simulator`.
Hope this help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use automatic signing on 'signing and capabilities'

Answer (score 0):

My case's

### Final solution:

- upgrade from `XCode 13.0` to `XCode` **13.1**

### Root cause

XCode's bug, not generated proper `Provisioning Profile` for iOS app/project

cause later:

- can not install app: `Unable to install`
- can not debug app: `failed to get the task for process`

both internal specific error reason is:

`A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found`

Answer (score 0):

For me none the answers worked.

The solution was for me to got to your project, then select your project under "**TARGETS**". Go to "**Build Phases**" -> "**[CP] Embeb Pods Frameworks**" and unselect "**For Install Builds Only**".

Yes, this is disabled in default, but I turned it on once for a problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to **Build Settings** and have **Excluded Architectures** look ***exactly*** like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to read the error reason before deleting DerivedData or messing with code signing. I didn't pay attention that in my case error was caused due to:

[image: Error details]

Cleaning the device helped :)

Answer (score -1):

## Xcode 11.2 is deprecated by Apple on November 5, 2019

Even if you can install it on your device, you can't pass AppStore: [See here for logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58754978/5623035)

Download [**the latest valid to AppStore version**](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2.1_GM_Seed/Xcode_11.2.1_GM_Seed.xip) xip file.

[image: Preview]

Xcode 11.2 had some issues and crashes [older iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58660634/5623035) and does not install on newer iOS devices. So for now you can:

## So The Solution is:

1. Update macOS to 10.15.1
2. Install [**Xcode 11.2.1 GM seed**](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download)
3. Build and install the app on the updated device (13.2.2 is out now)

Comment: Downloading Xcode 11.2.1 GM seed now... I'll let you guys know if it resolves the issue. Glad it's not just me - starting to feel like I'm taking crazy pills using Xcode 11.2.

Comment: Based on the linked SO post, the crash is relevant to pre-iOS 13 devices that have a `UITextView`. There's nothing in there about installation issues "on newer iOS devices"

Comment: That post contains many links since Apple produce chaos. @shim but now apple accepts the issue and deprecates Xcode 11.2 completely and removed it from the AppStore.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the problem, I tested the app deployment using Xcode 11.2.1 and the issue still persisted.  The only way I could get the app deployed to a device with Xcode 11.2.1 was to set "File -> Workspace Settings-> Build System" to "Legacy Build System"

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I haven't even been able to unarchive the folder. In the middle of it now - oddly it seems to stop every time it's almost finished unpacking. Anyone know how large this folder is? And should it be taking forever to unpack?

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes it gets long time, even it's Calculating Size takes forever so I can't tell you how large is it. @Brittany