# App archived with Xcode 11.2 (11B52) rejected: ITMS-90534: Invalid Toolchain

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, toolchain, macos-catalina

I have installed both Catalina and Xcode 11 from store and they are up to date:

- Catalina: 10.15.1 (19B88)
- Xcode: 11.2 (11B52)

Yesterday I have uploaded a new binary using `fastlane`. Today I got this message from Apple:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent submission for App
>   Store review for your app, "Gözen Security" 7.3.2 (67). Please correct
>   the following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90534: Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with an unsupported
>   version of Xcode or SDK. If you plan to submit this build to the App
>   Store, make sure you are using the GM version of Xcode 10.1 and the
>   SDK for iOS 12.1 and watchOS 5.1, Xcode 7.1 and the SDK for tvOS 9, or
>   Xcode 6 and the SDK for macOS 10.9 or later. If you are using an Xcode
>   beta version to test your app, make sure you are using the latest
>   supported version. For more information about supported beta versions,
>   view the App Store Connect What's New page
>   (https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/whats-new/).
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

Since `Catalina` and `Xcode 11` are officially released why `Apple` still want me to use `Xcode 10` and `iOS 12`?

Comment: Is that all description of the error?

Comment: yes it is all of the message

Comment: downloading the 11.2.1 from developer site

Comment: Apple softwares have even more bugs then mine.

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Xcode, try to keep one

Comment: No I have only one, Xcode 11.

Comment: @SalmanKhalid still downloading, internet is slow in my company :)

Comment: I had the same problem, just download **Xcode 11.2.1 (11B53)**… That solved my problem…

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2.1_GM_Seed/Xcode_11.2.1_GM_Seed.xip

for anyone that needs the download link

Comment: Not a duplicate! Last time the solution was to use the latest release version, this time it's to use the latest beta version. Since the answers to the other question don't apply, can someone remove the Duplicate tag?

Comment: I agree with Alex Wally - not a duplicate. This question is specific to a mistake Apple made, in releasing Xcode 11.2 into app store, with this severe bug. Everyone who is having this problem *does not have two versions of xcode*, and is using the *latest officially released Apple version of Xcode*.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Xcode was updated to 11.2.1 version. Builds made in Xcode ver 11.2 are not valid anymore. If you do not see the update in the Mac App Store then go to your developer account and download new Xcode manually.

Comment: Apple announced any official news that it won't accept any build made by Xcode 11.2?

Comment: Usually Apple accepts builds made by previous XCode Versions.

Comment: you can make a build in 11.2 and try to upload it. you will get the error description that said what I am talking about

Comment: 11.2 is the latest version for me, or is "GM seed" a release version?

Comment: @Halpo yep, GM means release

Comment: bad apple. i can't update to latest xcode version of 11.2.1 from app store NOWWWW. because current  version of app store is 11.2.

Comment: Version 11.2 introduced a serious bug that would not allow the upload either due to problem with the UITextview. That is why they took the action. But really they shouldn't have deprecated 11.2 without making 11.2.1 immediately available. It is available as a download under developer site now but yesterday it wasn't. Just bad timing. Hope 11.2.1 works and doesn't introduce another serious bug.

Comment: @TomMarvoloRiddle - you can download the 11.2.1 from the Apple Developer downloads.
I agree though that the iOS13.2/ Xcode 11.2 release was quite a mess. First releasing an official iOS update that was not yet supported by the official XCode release… then these 11.2 issues.

Comment: I installed 11.2.1 GM last week, but it made no difference. I still get the "Invalid toolchain" error. I've made sure that the command line tools refer to 11.2.1, but still the upload fails.

Comment: Do anyone knows whether Xcode 11.1 is still okay for Testflight or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, but you will not be able to support iOS 13.2.

Comment: Thank you @kirander. I am aware of that. I was just curious.

Comment: After downloading and installing Xcode 11.2.1, I am stuck in an endless loop where I am prompted to install Command Line tools whenever I try to do a "git clone" on the command line.  What a disaster!

Answer (score 8):

## Xcode 11.2 is deprecated by Apple on November 5, 2019

---

## Always working workaround (Manual download)

[**Download the xip file from here**](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2.1/Xcode_11.2.1.xip)

Also:

> > ## [Latest Release version](https://developer.apple.com/download/release/) (Xcode 11.2.1)
>
> or
>
> > #### [Latest Beta version](https://developer.apple.com/download/) (Xcode 11.3 Beta)
>
> or
>
> > #### [Any version you need](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). And all other downloadable contents

Then extract and move it where you like.

You can find [all workaround histry of the issue here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58660634/5623035)

Comment: Hello! How do you mean deprecated? I thought this is still valid: "Starting April, 2020, all iPhone and iPad apps submitted to the App Store will need to be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later. They must also support the all-screen design of iPhone XS Max or the 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation), or later." from Apple side. Link for it: https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/.

Comment: @F3R1 this is not about iOS, this is about Xcode, if you try to upload your app to the AppStore, you will get errors showing that Xcode 11.2 and below is deprecated [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58748855/5623035)

Comment: Yeah I see. Let me put this into a context. I thought that until April 2020 you are allowed to upload an app with even the latest stable Xcode 10 version, and every Xcode 11 version which just came after that. But apparently this is not the case. As far as I see you can only upload an app to AppStore with a stable Xcode 10 version or with a stable Xcode 11 version which is (Xcode 11.2.1 now).

Comment: Unfortunately Apple is not predictable for a while now.