# App store app uploading failed with ERROR ITMS-90534 and WARNING ITMS-90703

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode11

I'm trying to upload the app to the app store. But getting the error as below:

App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain. Your app was built with an unsupported version of Xcode or SDK. If you plan to submit this build to the App Store, make sure you are using the GM version of Xcode 10.1 and the SDK for iOS 12.1 and watchOS 5.1, Xcode 7.1 and the SDK for tvOS 9, or Xcode 6 and the SDK for macOS 10.9 or later. If you are using an Xcode beta version to test your app, make sure you are using the latest supported version. For more information about supported beta versions, view the App Store Connect What's New page (https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/whats-new/)."

App Store Connect Operation Warning
WARNING ITMS-90703: "Deprecated Xcode Build. Due to resolved app archives issues, we have deprecated Xcode 11.2 on November 5, 2019. Download Xcode 11.2.1 or newer, rebuild your app and resubmit."

WARNING ITMS-90703 states that Xcode 11.2 is deprecated. Download 11.2.1 or newer, but Apple has not released the newer version after Xcode 11.2.

Please advise how to resolve this error.

[image]

Comment: The same for me. I don't see any updates for XCode.

Comment: “but Apple has not released the newer version after Xcode 11.2.” That is not true.

Comment: Didn’t you get your answer?

Answer (score 14):

## Xcode 11.2 is deprecated by Apple on November 5, 2019

---

## Always working workaround (Manual download)

[**Download the xip file from here**](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2.1/Xcode_11.2.1.xip)

Also:

> > ## [Latest Release version](https://developer.apple.com/download/release/) (Xcode 11.2.1)
>
> or
>
> > #### [Latest Beta version](https://developer.apple.com/download/) (Xcode 11.3 Beta)
>
> or
>
> > #### [Any version you need](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). And all other downloadable contents

Then extract and move it where you like.

You can find [all workaround histry of the issue here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58660634/5623035)

Comment: I have only used XCode versions from the AppStore before. If I install the GM seed 11.2.1 from Apple Developer, please can someone tell me what exactly do I do with it after expanding the .xip file?

Comment: Move it to application folder and use it

Comment: What I meant was will this remove the current version of XCode and will I thee have to download and install all the additional features and simulators. Me thinks this is not as simple as a standard XCode upgrade version. I am tempted to wait for the App Store version.

Comment: Xcode includes everything that you need! (Simulators, toolchain, etc.) and this is standard for developers, you think why it’s under developer.apple.com? ;) The AppStore way is more usual just because of the simplicity

Comment: I am sorry I am not making myself clear. I have used XCode for years but only installing it from the App Store. Every time I install a new version, I then spend lots of time waiting for it to download extra bits, e.g. latest versions of simulators and tools. I just wanted to know whether by using beta software I would have to go through this again or whether I should just wait for Xcode to automatically update itself when Apple finally get around to releasing 11.2.1 on the AppStore. I have read elsewhere that it is often better to wait to do precisely this. Any comment?

Comment: If you are about to release your app, you MUST download now. If not, it's totally up to you my friend. Personally I would wait for the release version if I could.

Comment: @SteveBrooker As you expected, update for **Xcode 11.2.1** now available on AppStore. If it does not show you in the Update section then go to the Xcode detail page and there you will find the Update option.