# Xcode 11.2 and 11.2.1 GM SEED -- Cannot install to device

Tags: xcode, macos-catalina, mac-catalyst

I've got an **Xcode Catalyst** / **SwiftUI** project that I had been developing under **Xcode 11.1**.  Under 11.1, everything works correctly.

When I upgraded to **Xcode 11.2**, I started getting the error:

```
Unable to Install "App_Name"
```

(where "App_Name" is the name of my actual app.)

If I click **Details**, it shows the following:

```
Details

Unable to install "APP_Name"
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620394
--
The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620394
Failure Reason: The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).
User Info: {
DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
"com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
0 DTDeviceKitBase 0x000000011f0e46e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
1 DTDeviceKitBase 0x000000011f0e4de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
2 DTDeviceKitBase 0x000000011f12456a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 164
3 DVTFoundation 0x0000000105db9156 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
4 DTDeviceKitBase 0x000000011f124301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
5 IDEiOSSupportCore 0x000000011efaca25 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
6 DVTFoundation 0x0000000105eea3ba __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
7 DVTFoundation 0x0000000105eeba92 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff6431a583 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
9 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff6431b50e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff64320ace _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
11 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff64321452 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff6432aa9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff6457471b _pthread_wqthread + 290
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff6457457b start_wqthread + 15
);
}
```

The result is the same under **11.2.1 GM SEED (19B88**).

If I go back to **11.1**, it works normally and runs on device.

If I try different iOS devices, it still fails.

If I create a new **Catalyst** / **SwiftUI** project from the Xcode template, it runs on device without issue.

Note that I also did look at this posting: [Xcode 11.2 - Unable to install App file to device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58662457/xcode-11-2-unable-to-install-app-file-to-device).  I posted this as a separate question, because the actual Failure Reason given, is quite different, and thus, they are most likely two unrelated issues.

Build device:  2018 MacBook Pro 15", running **macOS Catalina Version 10.15.1 (19B88**)

**Xcode 11.2** and **11.2.1 GM SEED (11B53)**

**iOS 13.2.2 on iPhone 11 Pro Max** *(also tested on iPhone XS Max and iPhone X with other earlier versions of **iOS 13**.)*

I've tried switching between **"Automatically manage signing"** and selecting manually, but nothing I've changed has helped.

Obviously **Xcode 11.2** is doing something different with respect to code-signing that's breaking this, but I'm not sure what.

Tried deleting DerivedData too, of course.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this based on some help from Ted Jucevic @ Apple (**thanks Ted!**).

The problem was the entitlements file was corrupted.

Here it is as xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key></key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.personal-information.location</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here's what it looked like in **Xcode**:

[image: App_Name.entitlements]

As you can see, right at the top, there is an empty item:

```
<key></key>
<array>
    <string></string>
</array>
```

This was probably supposed to be a **keychain-access-groups** entitlement, such as is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps).

Anyway, deleting that bogus entry above resolved it, and I am now able to build-and-run on device again.  I have no idea how it initially became corrupted, but I think it had something to do with **Xcode 11.2**.

Hopefully this info helps someone else too!

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the old version of the app from the device, and it worked.