# Xcode 11.5 not installing app on iPhone running iOS13.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

An app I was developing was running fine on my iPhone then after updating iOS, the app builds but does not install to the phone but works in the simulator. A message pops up saying unable to install "app name".

**What I have tried**

-Reinstalling Xcode

-Deleting and adding provisioning profiles

-restarting Mac and iPhone

-Create a new blank app

It still fails to install after all that I've done

Below is the details of why it fails:

Details

> Unable to install "CharliNote" Domain:
>   com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code: -402653081
>   -- There was an internal API error. Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code: -402653081 User Info: {
>       DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
>       MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000067)";
>       "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012830881a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233  1
>   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000128349f70
>   **90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke
>   + 155     2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010ef11155 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73    3   DTDeviceKitBase
>
>   0x0000000128349ca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken
>   installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] +
>   1654  4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001281c0e91
>   __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352
>   + 4165    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f0447f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK** + 7     6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f046436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194   7
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff67c226c4
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12     8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff67c23658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8     9   libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00007fff67c28c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597  10 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff67c295d6
>   _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363   11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff67c32c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596   12 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff67e7da3d
>
> ### _pthread_wqthread + 290   13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff67e7cb77 start_wqthread + 15 ); }
>
> System Information
>
> macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E287) Xcode 11.5 (16139)

Comment: Did you manage to find a workaround? Also having a similar situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 11.2 - Unable to install App file to device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58662457/xcode-11-2-unable-to-install-app-file-to-device)

Comment: Are you using any Framework or SDK? I have exactly the same error stack, with different addresses maybe due to a different iOS version (iOS 13.5 in my case). However, I only have this problem when building an app using Qt, so I suspect it to be the cause.

Comment: @Axel does my answer help?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I solved it. In my case, I wanted to re-use a NotificationContentExtension between various projects and went one step too far, removing basically every file from the extension. I fixed that by placing one file in the extension that simply inherited from the class that I wanted to reuse but had no further content.

The reason I could figure out that this was the problem was that I tried to install to the simulator instead of my device, and it clearly stated it could not find `NotificationExtension`. So definitely try to install it to the Simulator in this case, to see if it yields a more detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking "my extension is using my framework anyway, so let's move everything there", but Apple ruined dreams again :-(

Comment: Mine installs on emulator, but has error on device only.