# Unable to install "[AppName]" Xcode 11.5, iOS 13.5

Tags: ios, xcode, updates, ios13, xcode11

I recently updated my iPhone 6s to iOS 13.5 and I keep getting the error *Unable to install "app name"* with details:

```
Details

Unable to install "AppName"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620383
--
The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620383
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008021)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011beb081a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011bef1f70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101e91155 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011bef1ca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011bd7ae91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101fc47f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101fc6436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff689ce6c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff689cf658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff689d4c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff689d55d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff689dec09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff68c2da3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff68c2cb77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E287)
Xcode 11.5 (16139)
```

I have possibly tried everything like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960810/xcode-11-5-not-installing-app-on-iphone-running-ios13-5) or [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/glhkfg/xcode_the_maximum_number_of_apps_for_free/) but no luck.

It is possible to downgrade to a lower version without [losing](http://www.iphonehacks.com/download-iphone-ios-firmware) anything?

NB: Not part of the Apple Developer Program.

Comment: The report tells you what the issue is: The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.

Comment: I did remove all profile apps and still the same. And before everything use to work fine even having more apps

Comment: Did you also try the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953293/the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-reached-xcode/61978102#61978102

Comment: Thank you. I did, back up, reset and restore but your answer is probably what I should've done

Answer (score 2):

For those still having that problem. [Xcode 11.4 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11_4-release-notes) have it as a Known Issue:

> **Known Issues**
>
> - When targeting devices running iOS 13.3.1, tvOS 13.3.1,
>   watchOS 6.1, or later using a free Apple Developer account, app
>   extensions incorrectly count against the limit of three apps installed
>   simultaneously. When this happens, Xcode reports an error: “The
>   maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been
>   reached.” (59264389) (FB7568073)
>
> **Workaround:** Delete apps signed with
> your free account from your device and also remove any associated
> provisioning profiles from the device using Xcode’s Devices window. If
> your app contains more than two app extensions, remove them to remain
> under the three app limit.

The workaround suggested didn't work for me. Hope it works for some of you.