# Xcode 12.4 not installing app on iPhone running iOS14.4

Tags: ios, xcode

iOS13.5.1 is OK. But iOS14.4 not installing...

macOS Version 10.15.7 (Build )
Xcode 12.4 (17801) (Build )
iOS 14.4

```
Unable to install "MyApp"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
--
There was an internal API error.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000067)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012a70cc8f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012a74b241 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d81a64b DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012a74af82 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000012a5bba10 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3513
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d94917e __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d94ada0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff735766c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff73577658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7357cc44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7357d5d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff73586c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff737d1a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff737d0b77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
```

### System Information

Please...

Comment: Check your deployment target.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.
I couldn't change all the Deployment Target of the Project and Target and Podfile to iOS 12.1...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 11.5 not installing app on iPhone running iOS13.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960810/xcode-11-5-not-installing-app-on-iphone-running-ios13-5)